# java null reference copying

Tags: java, reference

Forgive me if this is a duplicate, I can't seem to find anything that explains what I'm seeing well.

The following program:

```
    Object a = new Object();
    Object b = a;

    System.out.println( "a: " + a );
    System.out.println( "b: " + b );

    a = null;

    System.out.println( "a: " + a );
    System.out.println( "b: " + b );
```

Yields this:

```
a: java.lang.Object@3e25a5
b: java.lang.Object@3e25a5
a: null
b: java.lang.Object@3e25a5
```

But **WHY?!?** I'm so confused by this. Shouldn't "b" be referencing "a"? Therefore, if "a" no longer references anything else (eg: null) then shouldn't "b"? I'm obviously missing something fundamental here.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**

I think what threw me off was I am printing out the address. For some reason, in my mind, I was printing out some magic value indicating the pointers\references - when in reality setting `b = a` is not making them the same, it is simply creating a new pointer to the same place on the heap. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`b` is not referencing `a` it referencing to the same object `a` is referencing to when the assignment was performed.

I know this is not same language but if you are familiar with **C**, it is like:

```
int someNum = 5;
int * a = &someNum; // a points to someNum
int * b = a; // b points to someNum too
a = NULL; // a doesn't point to anything (points to address 0), b still points to someNum
```

(I used C as it gives a clearer look of addresses and references)

Comment: Thank you. By far the clearest explanation - I knew I was missing something fairly obvious; or maybe I needed a refresher, DOH!

Answer (score 4):

Lets take a detailed look at what is happening:

```
//A is pointing to a new Object lets assume memory location for 1 for simplicity
Object a = new Object();
//B is now also pointing to memory location 1
    Object b = a;

//Both print the same they are both pointing to memory location 1
    System.out.println( "a: " + a );
    System.out.println( "b: " + b );

//a is now pointing to null, but there is no change to b which is still pointing to memory location 1
    a = null;

    System.out.println( "a: " + a );
    System.out.println( "b: " + b );
```

Answer (score 3):

Java always passes-by-value, that is all.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object a = new Object();
```

This line creates a new object on the heap, and puts a reference in the variable `a`.

```
Object b = a;
```

Java is pass-by-value, so this line passes/assigns the value of that reference into the variable `b`.

```
a = null;
```

This means the variable `a` should no longer point to that place on the heap, but should point nowhere. But it shouldn't mean that `b` points nowhere, since we passed the reference *by value*, so `b` is still pointing to that Object on the heap.

The key observation here is pass-by-value. Since essentially we photocopied `a`'s value into `b`, changing the original won't have an effect on how the photocopy looks since it's already taken.

Answer (score 1):

Both a and b are references to Object instance you created. It means that both point to the same memory area. Then you destroy one of these references. Now a points to null. But both object and the second reference to it b are alive. This is what you see.

Answer (score 1):

a references a new Object (`Object a = new Object()`)
b references the same Object as a (`Object b = a`)
a references nothing (`a=null`)
b still references the Object

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not premitive and it's considered as object, so when you call `a = null`, `a` will refer to nothing while `b` still refering to the same object `new Object()`